# Is there any better way to perform unpivoting without using Union All?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Please look into the below query

```
select 
    ca.cnsmr_accnt_id,
    cab.cnsmr_accnt_bal_amnt,
    [Balance Short Name] = 'LOAN_AMOUNT' --LOAN_AMOUNT 
from cnsmr_accnt ca
inner join cnsmr_accnt_bal cab on ca.cnsmr_accnt_id = cab.cnsmr_accnt_id
inner join bal_nm b on cab.bal_nm_id = b.bal_nm_id and b.bal_shrt_nm='OriBal' and b.bal_nm_actv_flg ='Y' UNION ALL

select 
    ca.cnsmr_accnt_id,
    cab.cnsmr_accnt_bal_amnt,
    [Balance Short Name] = 'BOM_POS' --BOM_POS 
from cnsmr_accnt ca
inner join cnsmr_accnt_bal cab on ca.cnsmr_accnt_id = cab.cnsmr_accnt_id
inner join bal_nm b on cab.bal_nm_id = b.bal_nm_id and b.bal_shrt_nm='CurBal' and b.bal_nm_actv_flg ='Y' UNION ALL

select 
    ca.cnsmr_accnt_id,
    cab.cnsmr_accnt_bal_amnt,
    [Balance Short Name] = 'CURRENT_POS' --CURRENT_POS 
from cnsmr_accnt ca
inner join cnsmr_accnt_bal cab on ca.cnsmr_accnt_id = cab.cnsmr_accnt_id
inner join bal_nm b on cab.bal_nm_id = b.bal_nm_id and b.bal_shrt_nm='CurBal' and b.bal_nm_actv_flg ='Y'

UNION ALL

select 
    ca.cnsmr_accnt_id,
    cab.cnsmr_accnt_bal_amnt,
    [Balance Short Name] = 'Total_Amount_Paid_till_date' --Total Amount Paid till date 
from cnsmr_accnt ca
inner join cnsmr_accnt_bal cab on ca.cnsmr_accnt_id = cab.cnsmr_accnt_id
inner join bal_nm b on cab.bal_nm_id = b.bal_nm_id and b.bal_shrt_nm='TotPay' and b.bal_nm_actv_flg ='Y'
```

Every thing is same except the **bal_shrt_nm** value. This is taking too long time. Any better way to perform the same operation.

Sample output

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your second and third are correct? They are identical except for `Balance Short Name`

Comment: @Martin, yes it's the same Balance Short name used twice for two different purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT ca.cnsmr_accnt_id,
       cab.cnsmr_accnt_bal_amnt,
       CA2.[Balance Short Name]
FROM   cnsmr_accnt ca
       INNER JOIN cnsmr_accnt_bal cab
         ON ca.cnsmr_accnt_id = cab.cnsmr_accnt_id
       INNER JOIN bal_nm b
         ON cab.bal_nm_id = b.bal_nm_id
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT 'LOAN_AMOUNT'
                    WHERE  b.bal_shrt_nm = 'OriBal'
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'BOM_POS'
                    WHERE  b.bal_shrt_nm = 'CurBal'
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'CURRENT_POS'
                    WHERE  b.bal_shrt_nm = 'CurBal'
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'Total_Amount_Paid_till_date'
                    WHERE  b.bal_shrt_nm = 'TotPay') CA2([Balance Short Name])
WHERE  b.bal_nm_actv_flg = 'Y'
       AND b.bal_shrt_nm IN ( 'OriBal', 'CurBal', 'TotPay' );
```

It still has `UNION ALL` but doesn't repeat the join four times and then `UNION ALL` the results.

Comment: it's the second query . However, it is giving an error "The correlation name 'CA' is specified multiple times in a FROM clause."

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar - Ah I just used an abbreviation for cross apply - I didn't notice you'd already used that alias.  Now fixed.